# Oozie error when trying to run a workflow in Hue

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

Im currently having trouble getting Oozie to work properly on my hadoop install.
Any input is appreciated as I`m a complete beginner in all of this.
I use:
hadoop 2.6.0 (with Yarn), oozie 4.0.1, hive 1.0.0, hue 3.7.1, pig 0.12
Its a local install which I run in pseudo distributed.
I installed everything from tars and configured it manually because sadly the one-click install from cloudera doesnt work in OS X.

Hadoop+Hive seem to work fine as far as I can tell, both in CLI and Hue.

Pig editor from Hue doesnt quite work yet, I can access and use files from HDFS but I get an error when I try to access Hive tables with HCatalog (ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader).

But right now its more important that the Oozie scheduler works, which it doesn`t.
When I try to run for example a shellscript in an Oozie workflow I get this error:

> Cannot run program "testscript.sh" (in directory
>   "/Volumes/WS2Data/hadoop_hdfs/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1427878722813_0003/container_1427878722813_0003_01_000002"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory

Now Im trying to understand what`s happening here: What is Hadoop trying to cache in appcache dir? The script? (there is no I/O involved in the script itself its just a simple shell command)

Afaik its hadoop that caches in those directories, not Oozie ,right? Then why wouldnt Oozie be able to find the application container? I can run mapreduce jobs with Hive without any problem, if Hadoop had a problem or misconfiguration concerning the caching this wouldnt work either?

I basically followed this guide http://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/ to install Oozie, except I skipped the part where he reconfigures the pom.xml for a different hadoop version, because there just weren`t any repositories for 2.6.0

I just built it as it came for hadoop version 2.3.0 with `"mkdistro.sh -P hadoop-2 -DskipTests"` and then just replaced the libs in `/libext` dir with the ones from version 2.6.0

After that I linked my `*-site.xml` files from `hadoop/conf` into oozies `/conf/hadoop-conf` folder.

The Oozie server is up and responsive, running a simple Pig script from Hue which uses Oozie works fine too (with the above mentioned exception).

Comment: The HCat error should be fixed with https://github.com/cloudera/hue/commit/97f80a4d251e0bf1852a0e0a59d488625d492b8d weird. Are you trying a valid script?
About 'testscript.sh', did you include it as a 'File' in the Shell action? Oozie needs to ship this file on the node where it will run it.

Comment: I only included the testscript.sh as "shell" not as "file"... including the script in both works fine now! Thanks a lot Romain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your shell script in two places when you create the shell action.

1. Shell Command
2. Files

The Files box tells Oozie to copy the shell script to the directory created for the job run.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as correct answer even though Romain already gave the solution to my problem in his comment, so it`s more visible for others to see.